# a certain simple sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions

I'm interested in finding the generating function for the [sequence](http://oeis.org/A221440) defined by the recurrence relation $$a(n)=3a(n-1)+a(n-2)+a(n-3)$$ with initial values $a(0)=3$,$a(1)=9$ and $a(2)=31$

There doesn't seem to be any useful information in the OEIS,thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving,

Comment: That's not complete enough to find the generating function, because we don't know the initial values $a(0),a(1),a(2),a(3)$. We can figure out the general form, however.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: I've added the initial conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With those initial conditions and the assumption that $a(n)=0$ for $n<0$, the recurrence can be written

$$a(n)=3a(n-1)+a(n-2)+a(n-3)+3[n=0]+[n=2]\;,$$

where the last two terms contain [Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket). Multiplying by $x^n$ and summing over $n\ge 0$, we have

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\ge 0}a(n)x^n&=3\sum_{n\ge 0}a(n-1)x^n+\sum_{n\ge 0}a(n-2)x^n+\sum_{n\ge 0}a(n-3)x^n+3+x^2\\
&=\left(3x+x^2+x^3\right)3x\sum_{n\ge 0}a(n)x^n+3+x^2\;,
\end{align*}$$

so

$$\sum_{n\ge 0}a(n)x^n=\frac{3+x^2}{1-3x-x^2-x^3}\;.$$

Comment: Brian M. Scott: thanks a lot

Comment: @Nicco: You’re very welcome.